# "0" From nowhere after cout

Tags: c++, windows

When i compile and run the program i am getting:The year you were born: 0
Where is the "0" coming from??
Here is the code:

```
//! Program written by Samer!//
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{

double Year, Age;
cout <<"The year you were born: "<< Year;  //!Here the error appears!//
cin >>Year; 
while (Year > 2017) //!That't a While loop!//
{
    cout <<"Please enter a valid Year:" << Year << endl;
    cin >>Year;
}
 Age=2017-Year;
cout <<"Your age is:" <<Age;
std::cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing `<< Year;`? at `//!Here the error appears!//`?

Comment: You seem to be printing the uninitialized `Year`. Reading an uninitialized variable can do anything, including returning the value 0. It doesn't seem like you intended to print it there though. Is it just a typo?

Comment: This is a problem for your debugger, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are streaming the variable `Year`:

```
cout <<"The year you were born: "<< Year;
                                    ^^^^
```

1. Your code is by design printing `Year`. This is what you have asked it to do. If you don't want to print it, then don't: `cout <<"The year you were born: \n";`
2. `Year` has not been initialized and using it in this way is undefined behaviour. In this case it seems to print whatever was in the memory at the time of initialization. In your case it happens to print 0.